# golang: Why must you dereference a FileInfo pointer to be able to access its members

Tags: go

The Go spec seems to indicates that you shouldn't have to explicitly dereference a pointer, but this appears to not work for FileInfo pointers:

> src/pathfingerprint/pfinternal/path.go:78: entry.Name undefined (type
>   *os.FileInfo has no field or method Name)

Obviously, `(*entry).Name()` works fine.

Why? What makes this works differently?

Comment: You probably passed a pointer to an interface not an interface to a function. Can you provide more context? Code where you use `entry`?

Comment: `os.FileInfo` is an interface, not a struct. You've probably made a mistake if you have pointer to one.

Answer (score 0):

> The Go spec seems to indicates that you shouldn't have to explicitly
>   dereference a pointer

What are you interpreting to mean this?

That question out of the way: You don't need to explicitly dereference pointers when they're hidden behind `interface`, but you need to make sure that whatever you're using as the interface implements that interface.

In English: You can create a struct which implements an interface, pass it or a pointer to it as that interface, and never worry about dereferencing. However: If you pass a pointer to that interface you'll get a compile time error because the interface pointer itself doesn't implement the interface.

[In code](https://play.golang.org/p/CmjV20QyjH):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Iface interface {
    Name() string
}

type Strct struct {
    name string
}

func (s Strct) Name() string {
    return s.name
}

func PrintName(i Iface) {
    fmt.Println(i.Name())
}

func main() {
    s := Strct{name: "strct"}
    // Strct implements Iface
    PrintName(s)

    // *Struct implements Iface
    PrintName(&s)

    var si Iface

    // Explicitly setting Iface to Strct works
    si = Strct{name: "Iface from Strct"}
    PrintName(si)

    // Explicitly setting Iface to *Strct works
    si = &Strct{name: "Iface from *Strct"}
    PrintName(si) 

    // Uncomment the next line to see the error when you try to use a pointer to an interface
    //PrintName(&si)
}
```

Comment: Understandable :) thank you